# "Специалист по традиционной медицине" или "специалист в традиционной медицине"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Как правильнее сказать: "специалист по традиционной медицине" или "специалист в традиционной медицине"?
Вариант "специалист в области..." я знаю и так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше - никак. Ибо правильный вариант вы знаете.
Но если уж очень хочется, то **"специалист трациционной медицины".**

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о книжных стилях (особенно официально-деловом или научном), по-видимому, лучше "специалист в области...". Словарь Евгеньевой, однако, дает примеры с предлогом ПО: "специалист по внутренним болезням", "специалист по анатомии".